# Automatically sending a 'Welcome' email to all new user accounts

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I have an Exchange Server 2010 Enterprise Edition on Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition x64.My question;

I'm trying  to do settings on http://www.ucblogs.net/blogs/exchange/archive/2010/03/23/Automatically-sending-a-_2700_Welcome_2700_-email-to-all-new-user-accounts.aspx
it doesn't working.additionally , it gives me the following result  when working powershell script

```
(New-ReceiveConnector -Name "Internal Relay" -Bindings 0.0.0.0:25 -RemoteIPRanges 127.0.0.1 -AuthMechanism None -Enabled $true -Fqdn "myserver.mydomain.com" -PermissionGroups AnonymousUsers -Server mysever | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights "ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient")

Identity        User                Deny          Inherited 
  AAAa\bbb   NT AUTHORITY\ANON...   False          False
```

In the above command, "Extended Rights" no information.

Any Suggestions?

```
$strScriptName =  $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
if (!(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name LastRun -EA SilentlyContinue)){

    # this is the first time the script has run - let's create the registry key and value for future runs
    New-Item -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation -EA SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    New-Item -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name "LastRun" -Value (Get-Date) -propertyType String | Out-Null
    write-host "Initial configuration completed." -ForegroundColor green

}

# get time stamp from registry so we know when it last ran
$LastRun = Get-Date ((Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name LastRun).LastRun)
$ElapsedTime = ((Get-Date) - $lastrun).TotalSeconds

$MBXArray = @(Get-Mailbox  -ResultSize Unlimited | ? {($_.WhenCreated -gt (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-$ElapsedTime)) -and ($_.ExchangeUserAccountControl -ne "AccountDisabled")})


ForEach ($mailbox in $MBXArray ) {
$strMsgTo = $mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress

$strMsgBody = "Hello, "+$mailbox.DisplayName+", and welcome to the Contoso family! Please keep this email for future use. It contains vital information.
$SMTPClient.Send($strMsgFrom,$strMsgTo,$strMsgTitle,$strMsgBody) 
}
# update registry here with a fresh time stamp
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name "LastRun" -Value (Get-Date) | Out-Null
```

Above powershell command doesn't working   on system  which installed  Exchange Server 2010 Enterprise Edition.
After it working , it gives me the following error.

```
HKLM:\Software\Innervation   registry key not valid.
```

How do I make the compatible with Exchange Server 2010  this PowerShell Command ?

Cheers,

Hope to see your expert advise soon. Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m utilizing this script with Exchange 2010 but I had to make a few small tweeks.  Also be sure your running this from one of the cass servers
First off change the PSSnapin to load the Exchange 2010 module.

```
“   if (-not((Get-PSSnapin) -match "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010")){ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 }   ”
Next, edit the $SMTPClient to match this line- “   $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("127.0.0.1")  “
```

After you have the script customized run this section of the command to create a reg key.

```
##########################BEGIN####################
$strScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
if (!(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name LastRun -EA SilentlyContinue)){
    # this is the first time the script has run - let's create the registry key and value for future runs
    New-Item -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation -EA SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    New-Item -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name "LastRun" -Value (Get-Date) -propertyType String | Out-Null
    write-host "Initial configuration completed." -ForegroundColor green
}
# get time stamp from registry so we know when it last ran
$LastRun = Get-Date ((Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name LastRun).LastRun)
$ElapsedTime = ((Get-Date) - $lastrun).TotalSeconds
######################END####################################
```

Then comment out the last line for testing purposes.

```
#########################BEGIN###############################
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Innervation\$strScriptName -Name "LastRun" -Value (Get-Date) | Out-Null
######################END#######################
```

Create a new user account and test your script till your happy.  After it works as intended remove the comment.

@Toshana

Comment: This doesn't work. I think the bug might be in this part. $MBXArray = @(Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ? {($_.WhenCreated -gt (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-$ElapsedTime)) -and ($_.ExchangeUserAccountControl -ne "AccountDisabled")}) It doesn't get any results.